# Mode property of ReactNative's Picker component does not work as expected?

Tags: android, react-native

The dialog mode of `react native`'s [Picker component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) does not show a dialog when set to "dialog", instead it shows the same default drop-down. I tested both the versions `0.59.5` and `0.60` - the most recent version as of writing this question- of `ReactNative`. Following is the sample code from [ReactNative's page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker) with slight modification, that I tested:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.setState({language: itemValue})
  }
  mode="dialog" //added this line
  prompt="Default Title" // also added this line
  >
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

I tested the result on android emulators with `API 17` and `API 23`.
Does this component have bugs? or is there something that I am not doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picker on Android is always shown as a dropdown, even if the mode is set to dialog. On RN 0.58.6 ,it was working fine ([Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24055))

**From react native version >= 0.59 this issue is coming and not fixed yet**

If you really need it you can use this package [AndroidDialogPicker](https://github.com/janczizikow/AndroidDialogPicker)